Create a True/False column based on a sequence of numbers in another column with python
I want to add a Momentum column to my df that takes True when I have three or more consecutive possessions and False otherwise.
I have this:



event
seconds_since_start_of_game
possessions




FOUL_RECEIVE
49.0
1.0


FOUL_RECEIVE
73.0
1.0


POST_OUT
86.0
1.0


LOST_BALL
101.0
1.0


2MIN_PROVOKE
122.0
2.0


FOUL_RECEIVE
137.0
2.0


POST_OUT
148.0
2.0


POST_OUT
306.0
4.0


LOST_BALL
324.0
5.0


FOUL_RECEIVE
362.0
6.0


LOST_BALL
376.0
6.0


FOUL_RECEIVE
399.0
7.0



and I want that:



event
seconds_since_start_of_game
possessions
momentum




FOUL_RECEIVE
49.0
1.0
False


FOUL_RECEIVE
73.0
1.0
False


POST_OUT
86.0
1.0
False


LOST_BALL
101.0
1.0
False


2MIN_PROVOKE
122.0
2.0
False


FOUL_RECEIVE
137.0
2.0
False


POST_OUT
148.0
2.0
False


POST_OUT
306.0
4.0
True


LOST_BALL
324.0
5.0
True


FOUL_RECEIVE
362.0
6.0
True


LOST_BALL
376.0
6.0
True


FOUL_RECEIVE
399.0
7.0
True




How do you define "possessions"? The provided doesn't seem to match the logic, only possessions "1" and "2" have 3 or more consecutive values

I don't want consecutive values but 3+ consecutive numbers in the possessions columns (1,2 return False but 4,5,6 return True) because many events can occur during a possession

Could you add one row with 6 and one with 7, what should be the output?

Should be True for both lines because what's matter is that the numbers in the possession columns are consecutive (it would be 4.5.6.7 so all good, and it doesn't matter if I have many 6)

I see, then it still wasn't clear enough and the solution below won't work. I'll update again

Now should work as you expect. I provided 2 different approaches :)

Yep, seems all good now, thanks a lot !

You could identify the successive values, then form groups, compute their size with groupby.transform and ffill:
s = df.loc[df['possessions'].ne(df['possessions'].shift()), 'possessions']

df['momentum'] = (s.groupby(s.diff().ne(1).cumsum())
                   .transform('size').ge(3)
                   .reindex(df.index).ffill()
                   .infer_objects(copy=False)
                 )

Output:
           event  seconds_since_start_of_game  possessions  momentum
0   FOUL_RECEIVE                         49.0          1.0     False
1   FOUL_RECEIVE                         73.0          1.0     False
2       POST_OUT                         86.0          1.0     False
3      LOST_BALL                        101.0          1.0     False
4   2MIN_PROVOKE                        122.0          2.0     False
5   FOUL_RECEIVE                        137.0          2.0     False
6       POST_OUT                        148.0          2.0     False
7       POST_OUT                        306.0          4.0      True
8      LOST_BALL                        324.0          5.0      True
9   FOUL_RECEIVE                        362.0          6.0      True
10     LOST_BALL                        376.0          6.0      True
11  FOUL_RECEIVE                        399.0          7.0      True

Intermediates:
    possessions  momentum    s  group  size  ge(3)
0           1.0     False  1.0    1.0   2.0  False
1           1.0     False  NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
2           1.0     False  NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
3           1.0     False  NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
4           2.0     False  2.0    1.0   2.0  False
5           2.0     False  NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
6           2.0     False  NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
7           4.0      True  4.0    2.0   4.0   True
8           5.0      True  5.0    2.0   4.0   True
9           6.0      True  6.0    2.0   4.0   True
10          6.0      True  NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN
11          7.0      True  7.0    2.0   4.0   True

Alternatively, using groupby.transform('nunique'):
df['momentum'] = (df['possessions']
                  .groupby((~df['possessions'].diff().le(1)).cumsum())
                  .transform('nunique')
                  .ge(3)
                 )

Intermediates:
    possessions  momentum  group  nunique
0           1.0     False      1        2
1           1.0     False      1        2
2           1.0     False      1        2
3           1.0     False      1        2
4           2.0     False      1        2
5           2.0     False      1        2
6           2.0     False      1        2
7           4.0      True      2        4
8           5.0      True      2        4
9           6.0      True      2        4
10          6.0      True      2        4
11          7.0      True      2        4


It doesn't work because then, I have three lines with 11.0, 11.0 and 13.0 value in possessions and your code return False (when it should be True because the values are reversed)

@CypEg yes, the logic of the question was unclear, now it is and I updated the answer accordingly
